# Has anybody used arcpy.mapping.ExportReport successfully on 64bit machine?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, reports, 64bit, background-geoprocessing

The **[online help for arcpy.mapping.ExportReport](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004v00000022000000)** says that it has some restrictions on use but does not list **64bit** machines amongst them.

I am running the following test from **IDLE** under **ArcGIS 10.1 SP1** (with **64bit Background Geoprocessing** installed) on **Windows 7 SP1**.

I've create a simple test.mxd (one layer called Suburbs in data frame called Layers) and a simple test.rlf (included Suburbs, said Finish to take all defaults, saw report and saved it as *.rlf)

However, this code (more or less straight from the Help example):

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\temp\test.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Suburbs", df)[0]
arcpy.mapping.ExportReport(lyr,
                           r"C:\temp\test.rlf",
                           r"C:\temp\test.pdf")
del mxd
```

throws this error:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 14:24:46) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\temp\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    r"C:\temp\test.pdf")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 181, in fn_
    return fn(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\mapping.py", line 515, in ExportReport
    return report_source._arc_object.ExportReport(*gp_fixargs((report_layout_file, output_file, dataset_option, report_title, starting_page_number, page_range, report_definition_query, extent, field_map), True))
RuntimeError: Error in generating report
>>>
```

Any thoughts on cause and/or possible workaround are welcome!
(My suspicion is that ExportReport may not be supported on 64bit machines.)

Comment: Doesn't ESRI use Crystal Reports for this? My guess is their library is 32-bit only. Does it work if you use the 32-bit Python executable?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Crystal Reports was excised and replaced by something open source nut from @JasonScheirer answer you seem to be right about it using a 32-bit library.  Is there an easy way to "use the 32-bit Python executable" without uninstalling 64bit background geoprocessing?

Comment: It depends on how you're running your script. If you're running it from within ArcGIS, just turn off background processing and it will use the embedded (32-bit) interpreter. If you're running it from the command line, you could specify the full path to the 32-bit python.exe. If you're running it from an IDE (you mentioned IDLE) it might have options to specify the interpreter executable location. I know PyScripter does, but I don't know about IDLE. See also: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Background_Geoprocessing_64_bit/002100000040000000/

Comment: Thanks for the ideas - I found the quickest thing was to just create a toolbox and add a Python script tool which I ran with no parameters in the foreground.  That worked perfectly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will work on a 64 Bit Machine, yes, but only from the 32 bit Python interpreter. [It is documented](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000062000000):

> The ExportReport function has a dependency on the ArcMap installation. Therefore, ExportReport can only be executed on machines that have ArcMap installed. ExportReport will not run using stand-alone installations of ArcGIS Engine or ArcGIS for Server. Moreover, ExportReport will not work as a Geoprocessing Service.

64-Bit Background geoprocessing *is* a stand-alone installation.

Comment: Could this be documented a little more explicitly, please?  Also, would this "just work" if I uninstalled ArcGIS 10.1 SP1 for Desktop Background Geoprocessing (64-bit)?

Comment: It would just work if you used the `python.exe` in the `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1` folder and not the `python.exe` in the 64-bit install's location. I hope would be an option in the Background Geoprocessing installer's setup to not set Python 64 bit as the default, but apparently not.

Comment: I found the quickest thing was to just create a toolbox and add a Python script tool which I ran with no parameters in the foreground. That worked perfectly.